# mOxie is undefined, yet very clearly defined

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, console.log

I'm pulling my hair out over IE9/8; I'm trying to use [mOxie](https://github.com/moxiecode/moxie), but it's showing up as `undefined`, even though it's very clearly defined.

when, from another file, I log `mOxie` to the console, it logs it perfectly fine in Chrome/IE10+, but firing the same script in IE9/8 logs `undefined`.

However, in IE9/8, when I type 'mOxie' in the console directly, it correctly logs the object.

http://jsfiddle.net/vxyayxy8/ -- Run in IE10 mode, and you'll see that it loads an object. Run in IE9 mode, and you'll see that it logs `undefined`

Why is it that in IE9/8, when logging from a file (that's included after mOxie), it's `undefined`, but is defined in IE9/8 when using the console directly?

Keep in mind that it's defined in Chrome and IE10+.

To test the theory of my answer below, in IE11, but in IE9 document mode, do `console.log({})` -- I get `undefined`, which fits the question and the answer. Can you reproduce this?

Comment: Yeah I'm with @BenjaminGruenbaum given the error manifests by just including the file you need to submit a bug over at Github - there is nothing we can do.

Comment: I am unable to repro the issue. I opened in IE 11 and went through all documents modes between 11 and 8. The object was logged each time. I also tested in an installed version of IE 9, and the results were the same - the object was logged.

Comment: @Loktar This particular fiddle should have no issues in IE 9. You may not be able to *author* a fiddle in IE 9, but you can usually *test* a fiddle in IE 9 to a generally-acceptable degree.

Comment: @JonathanSampson I authored the fiddle in IE9, and cannot come up with the results that you get. Fortunately, I have solved my issue, which resulted in a facepalm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*The answer below is still legitimate, but apparently it was due to an IE bug that I've now been assured has been fixed, so I'm installing updates and hoping for the best. Thanks for the help, guys.*

I've discovered that doing `console.log` in IE8/9 document mode (yes, the devtools are open) results in `undefined`.

Why they log an object as undefined is beyond me, but the fix is to use `console.dir` which results in the correct logging of an object to the console.

`mOxie` was never `undefined`, it was just being logged as such, through IE's bizarre implementation of the console.

Though I am getting claims that the issue cannot be reproduced, I can still get the same results,e very time I test it. http://jsfiddle.net/vxyayxy8/1/ -- This shows how log returns undefined, vs dir which returns the object.

[image: asdf]

Comment: This cannot possibly be the answer; `console.log` and `console.dir` do not determine the validity of a reference. You're either passing a defined value, or an undefined value. Which method you're passing it to is not relevant here. Please share the code you ran to come to this conclusion. Note: I work on the Internet Explorer team.

Comment: @JonathanSampson seeing as how you can't reproduce my issue anyways, it will be of no benefit to you to see it, but I will make a new fiddle representing the difference.

Comment: I would like to help determine the cause of this issue; but given the deterministic nature of computers and JavaScript, your posted solution is not possible. I sincerely mean no disrespect, but `console.log` simply will not return `undefined` for a valid object reference.

Comment: @JonathanSampson Well, I'm not lying, so either you're wrong, my computer is really a banana, or I'm stuck in the twilight zone.

Comment: Nick, I am not accusing you of lying - and I am definitely not wrong about what I'm asserting. I think we're running into a bit of confusion on the reliability of your test here. Would you be able to record your IE window and perform the test? [Here is what I'm seeing](http://i.imgur.com/VlRFb0h.gif).

Comment: Thank you; it appears you're not testing in IE 8 or IE 9, but instead switching document modes. Can you also log `typeof mOxie` and see what you get? Also, from the toolbar on your developer tools, I can see you don't have all of the latest IE updates. Can you run Windows Update, install all updates, and see if this issue persists for you?

Comment: @JonathanSampson it does return `"object"`, so it clearly does exist, but my console still behaves the way that you say is impossible. Is this an IE bug?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue on my end in IE 11 (but I have all of my updates). It's possible that this could be a bug in document modes that was later resolved. I'll investigate further. But as I was suggesting earlier, document modes aren't the most appropriate way of testing how legacy versions of IE will behave in a matter like this.

Comment: @JonathanSampson my IE is up to date, and installs updates automatically. If you end up coming up with an explanation, I'd be more than interested to hear you out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @NickDugger We shipped updates to Internet Explorer that redesigned the developer tools; if you still have the developer tools vertical and on the left, you still have more updates to install. Please check Windows Update again. I'll look on our end for a bug in document modes that may have been resolved in one of these later updates.

Comment: @JonathanSampson oh, I wasn't aware (I tend to avoid IE... for, well, I'm sure you know every reason under the sun, lol). I'll check for updates.

Comment: @NickDugger I am definitely aware of the reasons web developers aren't happy with IE (I was a web developer for 17 years before joining the IE team) :) We're going to change all of that with Project Spartan though ;)

Comment: @JonathanSampson Hey, I used to be an IE fanboy a long time ago. I'm more than willing to give you guys a fighting chance!

Comment: @NickDugger I found a developer tools bug from about 5 months ago that appears to be related to the issue you're seeing. Once you install all recent updates, I suspect your issue will be resolved. Please let me know if that is not the case and I will escalate the matter internally. Thank you for helping flesh out the details on this!

Comment: I should apologize for earlier too; I was wrong. I was not considering the fact that we could have introduced a regression into our developer tools. Thank you for your patience and helpfulness.

Comment: @JonathanSampson Nah man, thank you for personally taking time to help debug an issue that was apparently already fixed.

Comment: @JonathanSampson yet again, you restore faith in IE. Well done sir!