# window.applicationCache is undefined in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html5-appcache

I am working with Application Cache to save my page and so far everything works in Chrome and Firefox without a single error. In Internet Explorer however, I always get an error saying that window.applicationCache is undefined as soon as I try to use it. Entering `console.log(window.applicationCache);` in the console results in `undefined` too (just in case it was some problem with loading stuff). Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is your IE all the way up-to-date? I had a similar issue a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28283245/moxie-is-undefined-yet-very-clearly-defined/28284236#28284236

Comment: @NickDugger Yes, as far as I know (Version 11.0.96bla)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution: Someone put a `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8">`-tag in the head of the index.html so the IE pretended not to know `window.applicationCache` as it was added in version 10.